# Does the 'quality' of query optimization differ by database provider?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, optimization, cte

I don't have a clear understanding of query optimization in any database, other than that 'it happens'. Now I've just seen a ["medium" post](https://medium.com/@hakibenita/be-careful-with-cte-in-postgresql-fca5e24d2119) that discusses the pitfalls of using a PostgreSQL CTE in terms of optimization since the CTE is only evaluated once and that any optimizations that may be applied in terms of how the CTE is used, the database just can't apply.

But the example in the blog post seems trivial to optimize - i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = 500000;
```

vs

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT * FROM foo
)
SELECT * FROM cte WHERE id = 500000;
```

If calculation of the CTE is done lazily on first requirement then I would imagine that these two queries could be optimized in the same way (I think at least).

And that made me wonder... Would SQL Server be able to optimize such a query better than postgres?

Are there known differences between databases to the extent/ability they have in optimizing queries?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A question asking if something is "better" or "worse" is subject to personal opinions, so take this with a grain of salt. Asking about the behaviour of the query optimizer is usually extremely broad as the behave differently in complex situations compared to extremely simple queries as the one in your question.

For Postgres a CTE is (as of Postgres 11) a so called ["optimization fence"](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/). That means Postgres will optimize the CTE independently of the overall query. There are cases where this results in a "better" (=faster) plan, and then there are cases where this will result in a "bad" (=slower) plan (note that recently the discussion around this design decision started again, so maybe this will change in future versions after Postgres 11).

The example in your question is an example where this approach results in a "bad" plan as the condition of the outer query is not pushed into the CTE.

SQL Server optimizes the whole query including the CTE, so for your example the execution plan in SQL Server would qualify as "better.

But I have also seen the opposite in Postgres: when moving parts of a (non-trivial) query into a CTE the resulting plan was better because operations where **not** pushed down which resulted in better estimates and a much "better" (=faster) execution plans. As I hardly use SQL Server, I can't tell if there are similar situations there.

Comment: Yes, such situations occur in SQL Server (well, the reverse, because the CTE is expanded inline as if it was a subquery), and the solution there is typically to split up the query and insert the results of the CTE into a temp table first for further querying. This forces both the evaluation of the CTE to happen first, and gives the optimizer histogram statistics of the result. Depending on the query, either or both may be beneficial. Typically, you'd start off with CTEs (for clarity and to reduce unnecessary tempdb I/O) and introduce temp tables as necessary.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Yes I have seen things like that with Oracle too. The Postgres devs actually acknowledge that the current solution doesn't fit all situations. The main discussion around changing it is mainly: what should be the default behaviour and what kind of syntax should be used to control it (there are some proof-of-concepts patches that enable an "inline optimization" for Postgres).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, query optimization is different not just between database vendors (Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres, MySQL, etc), but also between different versions of the same database. For example, SQL Server 2017 has different capabilities than SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 1):

> I would imagine that these two queries could be optimized in the same way

And why would you assume this? Because mostly:

- Query optimizers are COMPLICATED
- They often are not greenfield - they grow over time.

Different statements may hit different areas of a query optimizer. They are a topic of extensive research, so they also differ significantly between databases.